# how do i access an existing ec2 instance through another instance in cloudformation template?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created 2 aws ec2 instances by using the aws- cloudformation template. Let's say i have the first instance to set up the oracle database, and the second instance to set up my server(there's one tool thats been included on the server side would set up the connection between database and server, and also create the database schema for the database). So my problem now is, is there a way I can update my database instance information(like, run some sql command) after the server got kicked up without writing any new java code? but update the info through the user data of the server instance? thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

User data scripts are only applied when the instance is first launched (see [user-data.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)).

If you want to run SQL against your database, you can do that like you would with any other database server, using the client of your choice.

Comment: Hey, THnaks for the response. So what you're saying is, there's no way I can trigger my previous db instance by launching any shell script nor from the command line? thanks,

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can do that in every way you can do it with any database - you can use a command line database client, a desktop GUI client, or any programming language using a suitable database library. The fact that this is a database running on an EC2 instance created using CloudFormation is irrelevant, it's still just a database that you can access like you would any other database.

Comment: gotcha! really appreciate this! :)